# Chat bubble with less opacity that denotes that the message is being sent to the Firestore Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, chat

I'm trying to make a chat application with firestore. I've done everything that's required for a chat app like sending messages and receiving messages with StreamBuilder. But right now, when a message is typed and sent, the chat bubble in the `StreamBuilder` widget gets updated after the query had been executed by the firestore. How can I display a temporary chat bubble with a slightly less opacity that denotes that the message is being sent like the one that we see on pretty much every app that has chatting feature?

[image]

The above is the result that I'm trying to acheive. The last chat bubble with the content `okay. what's up?` should have a less opacity until it's updated on firestore and turn to full opactiy after updated. How should I approach this with a StreamBuilder, if not what are the alternative approaches?

CODE:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:openmind/utils/constants.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: ChatScreen(),
    ),
  );
}

class ChatScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return ChatScreenState();
  } //
}

// Add the ChatScreenState class definition in main.dart.

class ChatScreenState extends State<ChatScreen> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  final TextEditingController _textController = TextEditingController();
  Stream firestoreStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("chats")
      .doc("david_aaron")
      .collection("david_aaron")
      .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
      .snapshots();

  void _handleSubmitted(String text) async{
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("chats")
        .doc("david_aaron")
        .collection("david_aaron")
        .add({
          "content":text
        });
  }

  

  @override 
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Friendlychat")),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: StreamBuilder(
                stream: firestoreStream,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    QuerySnapshot doc = snapshot.data as QuerySnapshot;
                    List<String> msgs = [];
                    doc.docs.forEach((e) {
                      Map s = e.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
                      msgs.add(s['content']);
                    });

                    // return Container(child: Text("DONE"));
                    return Flexible(
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0), //
                        reverse: true, //
                        itemBuilder: (_, int index) => ChatMessage(
                          animate: index == 0,
                          key: UniqueKey(),
                          text: msgs[index],
                        ), //
                        itemCount: msgs.length, //
                      ), //
                    );
                  }
                  return Center(child: Constants.loadingIndicator);
                }),
          ),
          Divider(height: 1.0), //
          Container(
            //
            decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Theme.of(context).cardColor), //
            child: _buildTextComposer(), //modified
          ), //
        ], //
      ), //
    );
  }

  Widget _buildTextComposer() {
    return IconTheme(
      //
      data: IconThemeData(color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary), //
      child: Container(
        //modified
        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Flexible(
              child: TextField(
                controller: _textController,
                onChanged: (String text) {
                  
                },
                onSubmitted: _handleSubmitted,
                decoration:
                    const InputDecoration.collapsed(hintText: "Send a message"),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4.0),
              child: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.send),
                  onPressed: () =>
                      _handleSubmitted(_textController.text) //modified

                  ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ), //
    );
  }
}

class ChatMessage extends StatefulWidget {
  ChatMessage({
    Key? key,
    required this.text,
    this.animate = false,
  }) : super(key: key);
  final String text;
  final bool animate;

  @override
  State<ChatMessage> createState() => _ChatMessageState();
}

class _ChatMessageState extends State<ChatMessage>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController animationController;
  late double opacity;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    animationController = AnimationController(
        vsync: this,
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: widget.animate ? 800 : 0));
    opacity = .7;
    animationController.addListener(() {
      if (animationController.isCompleted) {
        print("completed");
        setState(() {
          opacity = 1;
        });
      }
    });
    animationController.forward();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    animationController.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Opacity(
      opacity: widget.animate ? opacity : 1,
      child: SizeTransition(
          sizeFactor: CurvedAnimation(
            parent: animationController,
            curve: Curves.linearToEaseOut,
          ),
          axisAlignment: 0.0,
          child: Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  width: 200,
                  height: 40,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                  ),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, top: 8),
                    child: Container(
                      child: Text(widget.text),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ) 
          ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can initially have the bubble slightly less opaque bubble as the default for every time a user tries to send a message then use the `.then()` method to update the bubble color is the message was sent successfully and `.catch()` to trigger an error icon/toast if the message wasn't sent due to some error.

Comment: Can you add a code snippet?